# What does "Wenn $x$ frei für $t$ in $\phi$" mean?

Tags: first-order-logic

The (German) text reads further

> Wenn $x$ frei für $t$ in $\phi$, dann 
>   $$\vdash_L \forall x \phi \rightarrow \phi \frac{t}{x}$$

The *für* and *in* are confusing me. (I am looking for an explanation in either language, not a translation.)

Comment: Source and context? I find it even more confusing that the conditional clause no verb

Comment: It is saying that if $\phi$ is true for all $x$ then $\phi$ is true when $x$ is replaced by $t$.

Comment: "$x$ is free for $t$ in $\phi$" is a technical phrase, which as you see is not easy to explain just in terms of the words "for" and "in".  I usually take the quoted expression as just an abbreviation of a particular relation $S(x,t,\phi)$ which says that $t$ may legally be substituted into each occurrence of $x$ in $\phi$, according to the rules of a formal deductive system. It seems that the German and English versions are almost word-for-word equivalents of each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be "$t$ is *free for* $x$ in $\phi$", meaning that $t$ is *subsitutable* in place of $x$ in $\phi$.

In the quantifier axiom:

> $(∀x)B(x) \to B[t/x]$,

we need the proviso that the term $t$ is *free for* [or *substitutable*] $x$ in $B(x)$.

*Substitutability* is defined in order to avoid that, substituting a term $t$ with a variable inside (e.g. $y$) in place of $x$ into $\forall x B(x)$, the (free) occurrence of $y$ into $t$ will be "captured" by a quantifier $\forall y$ present into $B$.

Consider the following example:

> $\forall x \exists y \ (x < y)$,

which is true in $\mathbb N$.

Here $B(x)$ is $\exists y \ (x < y)$ and, according to the definition, $y$ is **not** substitutable [is not *free*] for $x$ in $B$. Why ?

Because the result of the substitution would be:

> $\exists y \ (y < y)$

which is clearly false.

Answer (score 2):

We can only expand on the conditions that need to hold for a substitution as this:

> For any variable $y$ that occurs in the expression $t$, the variable $x$ must not occur as free variable within the scope of some $\forall y$ or $\exists y$ in the formula $\phi$.

Here's an example why this peculiar restriction is necessary:
The following a true statement of PA ("the theory of $\Bbb N$")
$$ \forall x\;(x>0\to\exists y\;(y+1=x))$$
If we specialize by replacing $x$ with $7$ or with $0$ or with $2z+3$, all is fine:
$$ 7>0\to\exists y\;(y+1=7)$$
$$ 0>0\to\exists y\;(y+1=0)$$
$$ 2z+3>0\to\exists y\;(y+1=2z+3)$$
However, if we replace $x$ with $y+2$, disaster happens
$$ y+2>0\to \exists y\;(y+1=y+2)$$